# Use component as adapter and in adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I would like to reuse as much as possible my Android components. Here, I want to use a component inside an adapter and as an adapter too.

My first idea was to use a `Fragment` but the layout failed to inflate. Therefore, I assumed a fragment cannot be instantiate multiple times in a single layout.

I finally found a solution by declaring my component as a `BaseAdapter` and adding a static method for other classes (a hydrate method basically).

Then, I would like to know:

- If my statement about `Fragment` class is right
- If there is another way to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I have finally figured it out this problem.

Firstly, I was right about `Fragment`: Android does not allow you to inflate it multiple times in a same layout.

Then, the solution I have found is quite easy and cleaner than using `BaseAdapter`.

I created a `MyViewPattern` class and an associated layout, which can be included anywhere: either in an adapter or a classic layout. In order to hydrate it (fill it), I have just added a static method in my class pattern. This method fills out every element using provided arguments.

If you have any other workaround, feel free to post them!